# How to find all recurring VALUES from multimap<sting, list<string>>?

Tags: c++, duplicates, multimap

I'm looking for a way to iterate through the strings stored in the lists of all keys and find all duplicate strings, removing all copies but the first of each.
So, if my multimap was initialized like this:

```
 multimap myMap = {
  { "a", { "joe", "greg", jerry", "joe"} }, 
  { "b", { "alan", "joe", "harry"} }
 };
```

I want a result of this:

```
a= "joe", "greg", "jerry"
b = "alan", "harry"
```

This is the function I've come up with, but it's throwing an "Expression: map/set iterator not dereferencable". I've commented the line throwing the error in the following code. I'm fairly certain it's because I'm trying to derefrence the end() element which isn't valid, but no idea how to work around it. Can someone point to me to why this isn't working correctly? I haven't had a chance to test a working version of this algorithm to even know if it's correct (besides the obvious exception error).

```
multimap<const string, list<string>> getDuplicates(const map<const string,
                                                   list<string>>& animalsByEnclosure) { 

    multimap<const string, list<string>> duplicates;

    for (auto& enclosure : animalsByEnclosure) {
        list<string> allNames;                                                          
        for (auto& animal : enclosure.second) {
            const string anim = animal;
            int count = 0;
    //problem line follows:
            for (auto& ptr = animalsByEnclosure.end(); ptr->first < enclosure.first; --ptr) {
                for (auto findAnim : ptr->second) {
                    if (animal == findAnim) {
                        if (count > 1) {
                            allNames.insert(allNames.end(), animal);
                            ++count;
                        }
                        else {
                            ++count;
                        }
                        duplicates.insert(pair<const string, list<string>>(enclosure.first, allNames));
                        cout << "Inserting: " << enclosure.first << " and it's doubles:\n";
                        for (auto& c : allNames) {
                            cout << c << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << "Animal: " << animal << " not found.\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return duplicates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to traverse an STL container in reverse order, you should use rbegin() and rend(). E.g. instead of writing

```
for (auto& ptr = animalsByEnclosure.end();
    ptr->first < enclosure.first;
    --ptr)
```

you should write:

```
for (auto ptr = animalsByEnclosure.rbegin();
    ptr != animalsByEnclosure.rend() && ptr->first < enclosure.first;
    ++ptr)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you use a multimap, use it properly. There is no need for the value element to be an `std::list<std::string>`, just an `std::string` will be enough.

Now, to achieve what you want, you can maintain a set of the already encountered values while iterating over your map. If the value being examined is in that set, that means you have just found a duplicate and you want to remove it. You can gather that in a template function:

```
template <typename K, typename V, typename ... O>
void remove_duplicates(std::multimap<K, V, O...>& map) {
    std::unordered_set<V> values_set;
    for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end();) {
        // If we already met the value, we must remove it from the map
        if (values_set.find(it->second) != values_set.end()) {
            it = map.erase(it);
        // Else we register it for potential future encounters and move along
        } else {
            values_set.emplace(it->second);
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

You will find a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1fefc937acba121).